# C# WPF Toastnotifications action after snooze

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I created a C# WPF windows app in Visual Studio 2022

The app handles press on buttons, press on "Important" and dismiss just fine.
When using the Snooze button, the time has passed and the notification is shown again, then the events Now button and pressing on the text "Important" does not behave as before.

It comes into the OnStartup with argument of "-ToastActivated -Embedding" and no information about if it was the button or the text that was pressed?

What am I missing here how to tell events apart after snooze?

Some of the sourcecode:

```
      protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs sea)
        {
            if (sea.Args.Count() > 0)
            {
                String s = "args:";
                foreach (var item in sea.Args)
                    s = s + "<" + item + ">";
                if (sea.Args[0] == "RKToast.xml")
                {
                    ShowNotification();
                }
                else
                if (sea.Args[0] == "-ToastActivated" && sea.Args[1] == "-Embedding")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"ToastAction after snooze:\r\n{s}");
                }
```

In ShowNotification:

```
notification = new ToastNotification(xmlDocument);
notification.Activated += ToastActivated;
notification.Dismissed += ToastDismissed;
notification.Failed += ToastFailed;
...
```

xmlDocument is simple

```
<toast scenario="reminder">
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text>Text....</text>
            <group>
                <subgroup>
                    <text hint-align="center" hint-style="title">IMPORTANT</text>
                </subgroup>
            </group>
        </binding>
    </visual>
    <actions>
        <input id="snoozeTime" type="selection" defaultInput="1">
            <selection id="1" content="1 minut"/>
            <selection id="15" content="15 minuter"/>
            <selection id="60" content="1 time"/>
        </input>
        <action content="Now" arguments="action=[EXECUTE]" activationType="background"/>
        <action content="Later" arguments="snooze" activationType="system" hint-inputId="snoozeTime"/>
    </actions>
</toast>
```

Comment: I did not understand the following part _"But when using the Snooze button and the time has passed. The Toastnotification that are shown can't handle the events like Now button and on Importent pressed."_ Is that actually two separate sentences or rather just one? Does _"can't handle the events"_ mean something is different from what you expected, or rather that your event handler code does not run at all?

Comment: Sorry for the bad English, I have now tried to update the text. Hope that it makes more sense now?

Comment: Thanks for updating, Yes, I think I understood. am curious what the Toast experts will say